# Компилятор придирается

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    int integer1;
    printf ("Введите число: ");
    scanf ("%d", &integer1);
    printf ("Вы ввели: %d\n", integer1);
}
```

Почему выдает ошибку компилятора?

Comment: @rainprogrammer, Вы серьезно предлагаете всем погадать, какая у Вас ОС и компилятор?

Мне кажется, что если Вас интересует помощь, то имеет смысл указать эти сведения, а желательно также и **текст сообщения об ошибке.**

Comment: Рискну предположить, что не хватает int перед main.

Comment: и return в конце

Comment: @Nofate Как ни странно, в main return не обязателен =)

Comment: @Free_ze, смотря с каким компилятором работаешь - некоторые выдают предупреждения, некоторые без return не компилят

Comment: @margosh Конечно. Это считается дурным тоном. Однако, не ошибкой.

Comment: @Free_ze, это может стать ошибкой (не ошибкой компилятора, разумеется), если кто-то  извне вызывает вашу программу и проверяет ее код возврата. В C89 отсутствие явного `return` или `exit()` - неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

return 0;
}
```